# Distributions question. I'm getting the wrong answer?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An oil exploration firm is to drill $10$ wells, with each well having probability $0.1$ of successfully producing oil.

It costs the firm ${10}$ million dollars to drill each well.

A successful well will bring in oil worth $500$ million dollars.

Calculate the firm's expected gain from the $10$ wells. (Answer: $580$ million dollars).

My try:

I thought it was a binomial distribution.

Let $X$ denote the number of wells that successfully produce oil.

Let $Y$ denote the firm's gain from the $10$ wells.

$E[X] = 10(0.1) = 1$

$Y = 500,000,000X - 10,000,000(10) = 500,000,000X - 100,000,000$

$E[Y] = 500,000,000E[X] - 100,000,000 = 500,000,000(1) - 100,000,000 = 400,000,000 $ dollars

I don't know how they got $580,000,000$

Comment: Do you think maybe they just wrote the wrong answer or is there a flaw in my working?

Comment: Your number looks good to me.

Comment: The reasoning looks good too.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time one of these given answers are incorrect. If everyone's in agreement then I think I can just assume it was an error. Thanks

Comment: For what is worth I did the calculation and i found the same result.